# How can I create a report that shows contacts with no activities within a certain date range?

Tags: reports, custom-reports

I'm trying to create what my client calls a "Lag Report" that allows them to get a list of contacts with no activities related to them within a certain date range.

"Who are my contacts who we have not been in touch with in a month?"

I assume we'd want to start with a constituent detail report template, but there are no activity filters to add there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't know of it, there is a Custom Search available under 'searches' for Include/Exclude Groups. So you could use that.

Step 1: create a Smart Group based on Activities within timeframe (A)

Step 2: create a smart group of 'all individuals' (B)

Step 3: use Include/Exclude Search to say B minus A

Comment: This is good, but I'm getting stuck with smartgroups built on smartgroups.  once you use the include/exclude, you're limited to that search.  it would be much more helpful to have a search builder (like the next answer) but enable date ranges, so you don't have to manually change the date.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a smart group of contacts which has activities within a specified date range using Search Builder. Something like -

[image]

And then use `Constituent Summary report` to filter contacts belonging to this group.